# not able to install dependencies -vuejs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm-install

I have cloned existing project of 2019. I am trying to build it again. When i run `npm install` to solve dependencies. list of errors shown below i am trying to figure this out i have tried updating `npm update` and update all the dependencies still this error wont go.if anyone have solution please post it down than k you in advance

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\Mustafa\AppData\Local\Temp\install6659279533.cmd
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
npm ERR!   addon.cpp
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan_converters_43_inl.h(22): error C2664: 'v8::Local<v8::Boolean> v8::Value::ToBoolean(v8::Isolate *) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::Local<v8::Context>' to 'v8::Isolate *' [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan_converters_43_inl.h(22): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan_converters_43_inl.h(40): error C2664: 'bool v8::Value::BooleanValue(v8::Isolate *) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::Local<v8::Context>' to 'v8::Isolate *' [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan_converters_43_inl.h(40): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan_implementation_12_inl.h(103): error C2664: 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Function> v8::Function::New(v8::Local<v8::Context>,v8::FunctionCallback,v8::Local<v8::Value>,int,v8::ConstructorBehavior,v8::SideEffectType)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'v8::Local<v8::Context>' [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan_implementation_12_inl.h(105): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan_implementation_12_inl.h(337): error C2660: 'v8::StringObject::New': function does not take 1 arguments [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   c:\users\mustafa\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\16.13.2\include\node\v8.h(6196): note: see declaration of 'v8::StringObject::New'
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan_implementation_12_inl.h(337): error C2059: syntax error: ')' [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]     
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1034): error C2660: 'v8::Value::ToString': function does not take 0 arguments [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   c:\users\mustafa\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\16.13.2\include\node\v8.h(3048): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value::ToString'
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1044): error C2664: 'int v8::String::WriteUtf8(v8::Isolate *,char *,int,int *,int) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'char *' to 'v8::Isolate *' [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1044): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1818): error C2661: 'v8::Object::Set': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1824): error C2661: 'v8::Object::Set': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1830): error C2661: 'v8::Object::Set': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1836): error C2661: 'v8::Object::Get': no overloaded function takes 1 arguments [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1835): error C2672: 'Nan::EscapableHandleScope::Escape': no matching overloaded function found [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1842): error C2661: 'v8::Object::Get': no overloaded function takes 1 arguments [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1842): error C2672: 'Nan::EscapableHandleScope::Escape': no matching overloaded function found [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1847): error C2661: 'v8::Object::Get': no overloaded function takes 1 arguments [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1847): error C2672: 'Nan::EscapableHandleScope::Escape': no matching overloaded function found [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan_object_wrap.h(24): error C2039: 'IsNearDeath': is not a member of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>' [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!           with
npm ERR!           [
npm ERR!               T=v8::Object
npm ERR!           ]
npm ERR!   d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1859): note: see declaration of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>'
npm ERR!           with
npm ERR!           [
npm ERR!               T=v8::Object
npm ERR!           ]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan_object_wrap.h(67): error C2039: 'MarkIndependent': is not a member of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>' [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!           with
npm ERR!           [
npm ERR!               T=v8::Object
npm ERR!           ]
npm ERR!   d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1859): note: see declaration of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>'
npm ERR!           with
npm ERR!           [
npm ERR!               T=v8::Object
npm ERR!           ]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan_object_wrap.h(124): error C2039: 'IsNearDeath': is not a member of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>' [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!           with
npm ERR!           [
npm ERR!               T=v8::Object
npm ERR!           ]
npm ERR!   d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1859): note: see declaration of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>'
npm ERR!           with
npm ERR!           [
npm ERR!               T=v8::Object
npm ERR!           ]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\src\addon.cpp(36): error C2660: 'v8::Value::Int32Value': function does not take 0 arguments [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   c:\users\mustafa\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\16.13.2\include\node\v8.h(3107): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value::Int32Value'
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\src\addon.cpp(49): warning C4316: 'SHA3Hash': object allocated on the heap may not be aligned 32 [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\src\addon.cpp(76): error C2660: 'v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction': function does not take 0 arguments [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   c:\users\mustafa\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\16.13.2\include\node\v8.h(6802): note: see declaration of 'v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction'
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\src\addon.cpp(76): error C2660: 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Function,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>::Reset': function does not take 1 arguments [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!           with
npm ERR!           [
npm ERR!               T=v8::Function
npm ERR!           ]
npm ERR!   d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\node_modules\nan\nan_persistent_12_inl.h(25): note: see declaration of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Function,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>::Reset'
npm ERR!           with
npm ERR!           [
npm ERR!               T=v8::Function
npm ERR!           ]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\src\addon.cpp(77): error C2660: 'v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction': function does not take 0 arguments [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   c:\users\mustafa\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\16.13.2\include\node\v8.h(6802): note: see declaration of 'v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction'
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\src\addon.cpp(77): error C2661: 'v8::Object::Set': no overloaded function takes 1 arguments [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! d:\major project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\src\addon.cpp(97): error C2660: 'v8::Value::ToObject': function does not take 0 arguments [D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   c:\users\mustafa\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\16.13.2\include\node\v8.h(3060): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value::ToObject'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.0 found at "C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2017 (15.9.28307.2094) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Mustafa\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\Major Project\\final-year-project-master\\client\\node_modules\\sha3\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Mustafa\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Mustafa\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.13.2\\include\\node\\common.gypi',    
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Mustafa\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.13.2',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\Mustafa\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\Mustafa\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\16.13.2\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=D:\\Major Project\\final-year-project-master\\client\\node_modules\\sha3',  
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Mustafa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Mustafa\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\Major Project\final-year-project-master\client\node_modules\sha3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: Check your Node.js version and try to make that one match the used one back in the day.

Comment: how to check project node version?

Comment: It's shown in logs. "node -v v16.13.2". Compilation errors almost always mean that you use a combo of Node.js and platform that isn't supported by the package, otherwise a precompiled version is used. Here it's sha3 package. It's unknown what it's doing in Vue app, because it's serverside lib. Try to replace Node with earlier even version (14,12) if you're interested in running the project as is and you're sure it's possible at all. Otherwise the question doesn't contain enough details to fix the project